# Tag EIP with Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

Is it possible to tag an Elastic IP address with boto3? I know you can tag them through the console and I have tagged many of them this way but I can seem to find any documentation on tagging them with boto3.

I this is not possible with boto3 is there some other library I can use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The boto3 library offers a generic [create_tags](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_tags) method that can be used to apply tags to a number of different types of AWS resources, including Elastic IPs. Here's an example of how to use it:

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')

response = ec2.create_tags(
    Resources=[
        'eipalloc-094ca1234de5abcd',
    ],
    Tags=[
        {
            'Key': 'Description',
            'Value': 'Production EIP'
        },
    ]
)
```

**Note:** this adds the tag `Description=Production EIP` to whatever tags are already present on the resource (or it overwrites the `Description` tag if it already exists).

Comment: That worked. I was initially trying to call create_tags directly on the vpcaddress object as follows...


eip = ec2.VpcAddress(allocation_id='eipalloc-xxxxxxxxxx')
eip.create_tags(Tags=tags)/n
and it was failing because there was no method 'create_tags' on the object. I have tested calling the method directly off of other resources and it works but vpcaddresses appear to work differently.